# API to calculate drive distance between 2 US street addresses?

Tags: asp.net

Seems simple but users have no internet access.
The application will be hosted internally on as Intranet site. The application will be able to make webservice calls to the internet.
I tested and tried Mapquest.
However all the other providers seems to assume the users are able to access the internet so their API's are javascript based with src tags pointing to internet URL's

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Google for this purpose even if you aren't using JS. For example, in the Ruby world there's a [GeoKit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) gem that can do this. You can take a look at its source to get the idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have an intranet application that accepts the two addresses and calls a webservice also on your Intranet that forwards the request to the MapQuest webservice.

The MapQuest service returns the distance to your webservice, which returns it to your Intranet application.

Comment: Yes. Been there, done that with Mapquest. Was just looking other options.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you didn't like about that approach?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how serious you are about this requirement you can purchase Google Earth Enterprise which runs in your own data center and allows access to data without needing access to the internet:

- http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/earth_enterprise.html

Comment: Any ball park idea about the license amount?

Comment: no sorry its not something I have purchased. I expect its a custom quote depending on your requirements but there is a contact sales button on the page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

By your response to rptHarry it looks like you are looking for a comprehensive data set with working algorithmic programming to interpret the data for efficient road connections between points so as to completely be self sufficient. Even if you had this available, would you have the computing power to maintain/store all that data? Would you want to, how important can this function be? How much cost would be acceptable for this benefit?

But if you are looking for options that are more likely more reasonable, more information would be useful.
Examples:
Is there a predetermined list of possible addresses?
How accurate does it need to be? Is zip code to zip code accurate enough?
How crazy are you willing to get? (LOL) Like would connecting to a nuvy via serial port to send and receive the information through some kind of hack be a "viable option"?

Yes, nothing is impossible to me and I would go there btw.

Comment: I wish I could code such exotic apps. This is an in-house mileage re-imbursement app.